# about {} with only single values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have

```
wordList = {'word1', 'word2', 'word3'} etc.
```

It's not a dictionary because I don't have `key: value` pairs. Does using the dictionary brackets like this create a new technique that I haven't learned yet and if so, what is it called so I can read up on it?

If not, I'm assuming that the incorrect use of the `{}` is the reason I'm having trouble adding and subtracting from it?

Basically the premise is

> "If word in `wordList` meets certain criteria, add that word to `newList`"

Comment: Its a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: Don't forget to select a 'best answer'!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{var1, var2, var3, ... }` is the syntax for creating a Set. A Set is a collection that has no repeated elements and has no indices.

For future reference, you can use the `type()` method to find the type of any object, like this:

```
>>> type({'testing'})
<type 'set'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a set, there is the document:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use `{'word1', 'word2', 'word3'}` to define your value, actually it equals `set(['word1', 'word2', 'word3'])`.

You can try to check them:

```
>>> set(['word1', 'word2', 'word3'])
set(['word1', 'word3', 'word2'])

>>> {'word1', 'word2', 'word3'}
set(['word1', 'word3', 'word2'])
```

So, they are same.

If you want to make a dictionary object, the format is necessary to be combined of `key` and value as a pair:

```
>>> dict_ = {'word1': 1, 'word2': 2, 'word3': 3}
>>> print dict
{'word1': 1, 'word3': 3, 'word2': 2}
```

Although it's similar for brackets between `dictionary` and `set` , as Will Sherwood said, you can use `type` to check type of the object.